# SQL JOIN gives me 0 entry if stock has no product relationship

Tags: sql, join

SQL QUERY:

```
    SELECT 

         c.id AS c_id,c.image AS category_image,b.id AS p_id,b.image AS product_image,
         a.id as product_id,0 AS sc_id,0 AS sub_category,0 AS is_active2, a.*,b.*,c.*

     FROM stock_50644 a 

   JOIN product b ON a.product_id = b.id 

   JOIN category c ON b.category = c.id

     WHERE b.category=1 ORDER BY p_id ASC
```

If `stock_50644` has no `product` entry then i am getting empty result. How can i make it return all product with stock value null if stock is empty

EDIT:

```
PRODUCT                                  ; STOCK_50644
  id product_name        category_id     ;    id   product_id               price
---- -------- ---------- --------------- ;  ---- --------- ----- --------------
   1 name1                             1 ;     1   2                           15
   2 name2                             2 ;
```

if i put `WHERE b.id=1` in below query im getting correct expected output.

But as soon as i replace it by `ORDER BY b.id ASC LIMIT 1;`  it is taking forever time and then `#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

```
SELECT 

    c.id AS c_id, c.image AS category_image, b.id AS p_id, b.image AS product_image, 
    a.id AS product_id, 0 AS sc_id, 0 AS sub_category, 0 AS is_active2, a.*,b.*,c.* 

FROM stock_50644 a 
RIGHT JOIN product b ON a.product_id = b.id AND b.category = 1 
LEFT JOIN category c ON b.category = c.id 
WHERE b.id=1
```

> ORDER BY b.id ASC LIMIT 1;

Comment: try to provide small tables of queried tables and result table you want. this might help me understand you better. i think you need to right join product and and left join category but need a sample table to check this.

Comment: @TOlaleye Done. I have edited my question please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Move the restriction on the `category` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join:

```
SELECT 
    c.id AS c_id, c.image AS category_image, b.id AS p_id, b.image AS product_image,
    a.id AS product_id, 0 AS sc_id, 0 AS sub_category, 0 AS is_active2,
    a.*,b.*,c.*
FROM product b
LEFT JOIN stock_50644 a 
    ON a.product_id = b.id AND b.category = 1
LEFT JOIN category c
    ON b.category = c.id
ORDER BY p_id;
```

Comment: And `left join`?

Comment: left join is not working I'm getting same empty result. And by right join it is taking forever to load and getting 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' error. Tried `limit 1;` in the end. still taking forever

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited my question please take a look